# Tarantula droplets on the side

Tags: print-quality, tevo-tarantula

I have add my Tevo Tarantula for a couple years now and made a lot of modifications. The last in date is a direct extruder from Trianglelab with an updated X-carriage and a NEMA 17 motor for the extruder. Without counting the number of times I clogged the extruder I managed to get some prints, some of them can be considered to be of "okay quality".

But each and every time I got the same problem, very irregular print sides (see photo attached). I could not find anyone with the same irregularities on their prints.

Indeed, instead of making thin line layers, the plastic is extruded in forms of droplets. Hence the side of my prints have these uneven sides. I could not find a pattern so far (only on one side, or in one particular orientation) and I am having a hard time figuring out what is the cause.

As a possible candidate I am considering a X-Y stepper calibration problems (which I would not know how to address) as when the printer is active instead of going smoothly during long travels some motors are going by noticeable steps (unsmooth steps). I am a bit puzzled since I installed Trianglelab smoothers a while back and my prints quality really improved at that time...

If anyone has an idea I am very keen to have some heads-up.

[image: First layers in PLA]

[image: we can see long travels]

---

I have just finished my new print and please find the photos of my issues below. As you can see, there is a irregular side along the y-y axis. I usually saw problems from other people along the z-axis.

I have just launched a print with 110 % flow rate to see if I notice any difference. Now it’s on layer 2 and I still those little teeth on the side....

[image: along the x-y acis the side has a small indentation]

[image]

Comment: looks like either adhesion problems on the outline, shrinkage or underextrusion...

Comment: I am printing a new piece today with a perfect adhésion to the bed this time... I’ll show you the result in a few minutes.